# Make a date less specific in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a csv file with dates inside as index.

I use the command below to read the csv file :

```
pd_date=pd.read_csv("path/file.csv",index_col="created_at")
```

The output of this command is :

```
                    user_screen_name
created_at                                           
2019-02-22 03:27:07      ...   
2019-02-21 23:10:38      ...  
2019-02-21 19:09:57      ... 
2019-02-21 17:17:45      ...
```

As you can see, the "format" is :

```
2019-02-22 03:27:07           year-month-day hours:minutes:seconds
```

I would like to find a command to remove the hours, minutes and seconds.

The result I would like to reach is :

```
            user_screen_name
created_at                                           
2019-02-22       ...   
2019-02-21       ...  
2019-02-21       ... 
2019-02-21       ...
```

Thank you by advance for your help.

Comment: If any of the answers solved your problem, please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

You can use pandas datetime date function to return just the date:

```
str(pd.to_datetime('now').date())
```

returns:

```
'2019-02-22'
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for your answer. I am really sorry but I don't understand how I can apply this command for other date than today. For example the date "2019-02-21 23:10:38"

Comment: Hello! Now worries, just replace 'now' with any timestamp that you like, like the one you've given as an example there

Comment: That being said, @Chris has provided the code you need.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your help !

Answer (score 0):

Given `df`:

```
                     Value
Date                      
2019-02-22 03:27:07      1
2019-02-21 23:10:38      2
2019-02-21 19:09:57      3
2019-02-21 17:17:45      4
```

If index is `datetime`

```
df.index = df.index.date
```

If it is just `str`:

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index).date
```

And both yield:

```
print(df)
            Value
2019-02-22      1
2019-02-21      2
2019-02-21      3
2019-02-21      4
```

Comment: If I understood well I apply the following command :

pd_date.index = pd_date.index.date

The output of this command is an error :

AttributeError: 'Index' object has no attribute 'date'